# Call to a member function details() on null when assign model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Use model is:

```
public function details()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserDetails::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

First I create user model:

```
  $user = User::create([
                'email' => $request->inn,
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            ]);
```

Then I tried to assign details of users:

```
 $user->details()->create($user_details);
```

It returns me this error:

> Call to a member function details() on null

Comment: Try dd($user) right before creating the details to see if there is an object there

Comment: $user exists, I have cheked

Comment: What do you see in the logs? There may be a stack trace helpful to debug what is going on. Also `$request->inn` doesn't looking right to me

Comment: Can you check again? The error clearly says that it's trying to call `details()` on a variable with a value of `null`. Perhaps, you're not looking at the correct line

Comment: If this is your exact code, `$user = User::create();` followed immediately by `$user->userDetails()->create();` should work without issue. You might be overriding `$user` somewhere before calling `$user->details()`, so post your exact code if you can. Note: had to confirm, but `Model::create()` does return the created instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Two solutions for this.

### Create method

If you are using create method it's not creating object as you're doing right now.

```
$userid = User::create([
          'email' => $request->inn,
          'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ])->id;

User::find($userid)->details()->create($user_details);
```

In your question **$user** is not getting object that's why this error you are getting.

### Object Method

```
$user = new User;
$user->email = $request->inn;
$user->password= Hash::make($request->password);
$user->save();

//here $user is an instance of User so if you dd($user) you'll get an object.

$user->details()->create($user_details);
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided a lot of information with this issue however I would suggest that the issue is that the User is not being created because your attributes on the User model are guarded.

Make sure you have one of the following solutions on the your User model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'password'
]
```

Or

```
protected $guarded = []
```

Failing to add these means that Laravel will not allow you to add details to the model using anything other than `save()` method